# View width for dynamically added view

Tags: android

I want to show a notification counter like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:id="@+id/gvIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_reading"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTexts"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            style="@style/gridItemsText"
            android:id="@+id/gvText"
            android:text="Guten Morgen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/partNoticeTooltip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_tooltip_red"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tooltipWH"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tooltipWH">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCounter"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/h6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which has an output like this:

[image]

This is my expectation, but with dynamic way. So I wrote this in the `setOnItemClickListener` of my `GridView`:

```
    View tooltip                                    = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.part_tooltip, null);
    TextView tvCounter                              = (TextView) tooltip.findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);
    tvCounter.setText("" + counter);

    LinearLayout llText                             = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llTexts);
    llText.addView(tooltip);
```

the `part_tooltip` has exactly the same code but with another layout. And here is the output:

[image]

The red layout does not being displayed with full width. What am I missing?

Comment: @dimen/tooltipWH should be increased. check the value

Comment: Increased, does not work

Comment: Plz post the code of part_tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a global layout listener and also the view tree observer:

```
ViewTreeObserver mVTO = parentLayoutOfTheViewAddedDynamically.getViewTreeObserver();
    mVTO.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {


        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if(viewAddedDynamically != null){

                int viewWidth = viewAddedDynamically.getWidth();
          //    any operation based on viewWidth is to be done here
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: `any operation based on viewWidth is to be done here` please tell me what kind of operation required?

Comment: what view's width u want to measure dynamically; and use that measured width to achieve what;